# How can i launch bash-script on Mac os with automator-app in same directory?

Tags: bash, macos, path, launch, automator

I searched here and on the net, but didn't really find what I was looking for (I'm still a newbie in bash programming).

**I want to start a small bash-script via automator-app.**
My bash-script and the automator-app should be in the same directory. The app should just start the script (without parameters). (The script manipulates files in the directory where it is located).
I don't want to copy the script somewhere and have the app somewhere else, both should be in the same directory.
However, Automator does not find the bash script.
How can I specify the path correctly?

In Automator I said:

> Run-Shell-Script

> myshellscript.sh

**myshellscript.sh -> is not found.** And I don't want a fixed path. The path of the app (and script) should be my working path.

Can someone help me? That would be great.

## **Solution found:**

```
property myPath : ""
set myPath to POSIX path of ((path to me as text) & "::") as text
do shell script myPath & "myscript.sh " & myPath
```

Comment: Have you tried the answers to this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918497/applescript-run-bash-script-from-same-directory

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I looked there, but in the end the following helped:
property myPath : ""
set myPath to POSIX path of ((path to me as text) & "::") as text
do shell script myPath & "myscript.sh " & myPath